# avformat_find_stream_info not return on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, ffmpeg

I want to fetch the camera video stream on both windows and linux.The code goes everything well with windows.But when I transplant it to Linux,function avformat_find_stream_info can Not return!

```
bool VideoFetcher::enumCamera(){
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    AVInputFormat *pInputFormat = av_find_input_format(
        #ifdef __WIN32
                "dshow"
        #elif __linux
                "v4l2"
        #else
                ""
        #endif
                );
    assert(pInputFormat);
#ifdef __linux
    char str[128];
    sprintf(str, "/dev/video%d", i);
#endif
    AVDictionary* dictionary = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&dictionary, "video_size", "640x480", NULL);
    //av_dict_set(&dictionary, "framerate", "30", NULL);
    if (avformat_open_input(
                &this->cameraFormatContext,
        #ifdef __WIN32
                (std::string("video=")+this->getCameraName()).c_str(),
        #elif __linux
                str,
        #else
         ""
        #endif
                pInputFormat, &dictionary)
            < 0)
            {

                    Log("Error : Couldn't open the camera\n");
            }else{
                    return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
 }
assert(avFormatContext);
// int streamError;
auto streamError = avformat_find_stream_info(avFormatContext, NULL);
//the function can not return !
printf("findcodec1\n");
if (streamError< 0){
        throw StreamErrorException();
 }
```